# Magento v1.9x migrated from shared hosting to vps getting multiple bugs and error

Tags: migration, magento-1.9, vps, shared-hosting, browser-bugs

Im new in magento, **I migrated my magento website from shared hosting to VPS.** 
and now my website is getting multiple **bugs and errors**:

**1. when user registered they redirected on different page. 
2. when buyer place their order they redirected to EMPTY SHOPPING CART.
3. payment method are not working (like: dragonpay).**

my website is working fine when it is on shared hosting but now my website is experiencing these kind of bugs and error.

I Highly appreciate your Help.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks a little unclear to me. There could be multiple reasons so we might need more information for that.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas thnx for your reply. actually i have no idea where the problem was coming from, but, I'm thinking about the cookies since when you visit the site for the first time, you may able to add cart, then you can proceed to checkout successfully but when you try to re-order; and try to add to cart for your second purchase you will be sending to Empty shopping cart continuously.